# Cannot read property 'get' of undefined at Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently programming my own discord.js bot but always getting the same Error: "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" at a module that sends me the message another user send me in a private dm. Here's the Code:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  Client.users.get("738346395416789022").send(`${message.author.username} said ${message.content}`);
});
```

Could anyone help me debugging this issue ?

Comment: Did you mean `client` instead of `Client`?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a Typo , It should be `client.users.cache.get` instead of `Client.users.cache.get`

Comment: It might be just `client.user.get` if OP is using discord.js v11 or later

Comment: `client.users.fetch()` as of v12